# Purpose of multiple template declarations of same type

Tags: c++, cuda

I have come across a code base which has multiple declarations and there is only one CUDA kernel `density(...)`

```
template __global__ void density<5>(int width, int height);
template __global__ void density<4>(int width, int height);
template __global__ void density<3>(int width, int height);
template __global__ void density<2>(int width, int height);
template __global__ void density<1>(int width, int height);
```

These are called via `switch-case` mechanism based on a value given. The kernel itself is defined as

```
template<int N>
__global__ void density(int width, int height){...}
```

We could simply pass the variable `int N` to the kernel itself instead of defining 5 different template parameter explicitly. What is the purpose of such definition?

P.S: The value of `int N` is known only during runtime.

Comment: Where did you find this code? What is the context of it? Have you tried to look at any possible documentation or references? Tried to contact the author of the code?

Comment: This is just a codebase within the company. No available docs and the original author is not in the company anymore.

Comment: I suspect if the original purpose was something "more" but the "more" part was never implemented?

Comment: *"which has multiple declarations"* Those are [explicit instantiations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_instantiation)

Answer (score 4):

Those are instructions to the compiler to instantiate that function (generate and compile actual code, and provide a function for linkage) with that template configuration.   The usual reason for this is to enable external linkage, so that the variants are available and compiled so that they can be called from another compilation unit.  A template function defined in compilation unit A, cannot be configured and compiled in compilation unit B.  If compilation unit B wants to use that function, a suitable variant must have been compiled in compilation unit A.

A typical reason for the template parameter itself, is because the code designer concluded that the compiler may be able to optimize the code better if the template argument is known at compile-time (which it is for a template argument) as opposed to passing the number via a runtime argument via ordinary function parameters.

The reason to template-instantiate those 5 types specifically is because the code designer determined that those would be the ones needed in practice, or based on study of the external linkage needs.

Even if the argument N is only known at runtime, it is possible, if the range is limited, to instantiate each variant, and get the compile-time optimization benefit, if any.

In such a situation, it is possible to use a switch-case to dispatch the various variants, based on run-time parameter:

```
switch(runtime_N) {
  case 1:
    density<1><<<...>>>(width, height);
    break;
  case 2:
    density<2><<<...>>>(width, height);
    break;
  case 3:
    density<3><<<...>>>(width, height);
    break;
  case 4:
    density<4><<<...>>>(width, height);
    break;
  case 5:
    density<5><<<...>>>(width, height);
    break;
  default:
    density_unoptimized_for_N(width, height, runtime_N);
    break;
}
```

Even if the runtime distribution of N exceeds the range 1..5, if the code designer has determined that the most frequently occurring usage will be in the range of 1..5, then the above switch-case structure allows the program to extract "most" of the benefit of treating N as a compile-time constant, even though it is not.

None of this is unique or specific to CUDA, but represents general C++.